# ID Change with Vgs for MOSFETS

Tags: mosfet

im currently picking a mosfet for a project.
Im looking for a mosfet that has an Id of 10 amps+ at 3.3v. I found the [16NF06L](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A200/TXSTM-POWERMOSFET-STX-16NF06L_EN.pdf) but have a problem understanding the datasheet. It says that Id is 16A. Figure 5 shows (to my understanding) that at 3.3v Vgs the mosfet should be able to handle around 13 Amps (with Vds > 2V).
So far so good. But when i look at the RDS(on) line in the table the test condition colum shows that Id is 8A at both 5V and 10V Vgs. That seems to contradict what the figure shows. What does ID mean in the context of RDS(on)? To my understanding Id always means max. current under given conditions (Vgs, Temp, Vds etc.). I only started learing about mosfets today, so maybe im missing out on something obvious.

Hope you can help.

Comment: FIg 5 is the test circuit - unfortunately the charts are not numbered can you describe better which one you are referring to?

Comment: You said the following: "To my understanding Id always means max. current under given conditions (Vgs, Temp, Vds etc.)" However, I used to think that we don't usually care too much about max Id, becuse our Id when operation is almost under Id max. We bother more on Max/Min/Typ of Vgs(Th) / Ron. Eg, for Vgs(th) I usually look at Vgs(th) which I think is most important, because I need to be guaranteed that if my Vgs is under max Vgs(th), my MSOFET should at least begin to conduct, min/typ values do not guarantee that. / to continue, ...

Comment: We might like to look at some pictures to clarify things: https://i.imgur.com/lFpQ9zM.jpeg.

Comment: Referring to above picture, we know at Vgs = 10V, we can easily have Id > 20A. But for Vgs = 3V, then Id can only be around 12A. Also for Id = 4A < 16A, Rds(on) is only < 100mΩ, which is very small, compared with power NPN BJT, so for small current applications, Rds(on) can safely be ignored, or just use a very small heat sink to take car of that.

Comment: _"Im looking for a mosfet that has an Id of 10 amps+ at 3.3v."_ - For what purpose?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott, me too looking for Vd max 10A, ***Vgs(th) max 3V***, because I am doing Micky Mouse projects using 3V3 Rpi4B and toy BLDC motors < 10A stall. I used to play with IRF540N but found their Vgs > 7V useless, and worst of all that most of the > 5 years old references/tutorial are on Vgs > 5V. So after googling, I found IRL540N is good for 3V3 Rpi or Arduino toy projects.

Comment: This FET is not appropriate for your application because it is not qualified to switch on fully with 3.3V. It might be OK for current << 10A _if_  the Gate threshold is at the lower end of the spec., but to be sure you should get a FET rated for 2.5V Gate drive.

Comment: I agree, so I am looking for ***Vgs(off) max < 2V***. See my recommended NTE Low Vgs FET selection guide at Reference 7 of my answer to the following question: Solution for how to drive a P-Channel MOSFET when Gate/Source voltage is too low?
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518061/solution-for-how-to-drive-a-p-channel-mosfet-when-gate-source-voltage-is-too-low/518071#518071.

Comment: the RDS test condition just specifies how much R was found at a typical I value and two Vgs values, not the max of anything.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott So just to clarify. The Vds vs Id chart that shows me that Id is ~7A at 3V Vgs. Doesn't mean that i can safely pass (e.g.) 6A through the FET at 3V Vgs? Why does it have to switch on fully, isn't it enough if the chart shows that Id is sufficient for my needs at my given Vgs?

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks for you explanation. Turns out, my definition if Id was wrong.

Comment: @rogerg, Ah, as you are just started learning MOSFET today, I think you are quick in discovering and admitting you misunderstood the definition of Id. I remember when I was a MOSFET newbie I spent some 20 hours studying, misinterpret the spec a couple of times, before I got a rough idea of what is going on. So I think that newbies making mistakes is good, because making mistakes and correcting them is a good way of learning and remembering. / to continue, ...

Comment: You just asked a critical question: Why we require channel fully open, if partially open channel with 3V Vgs and 6A Id already meets requirement. I think it is an engineering trade off, or cost benefit analysis question. You might have skimmed my old answer, that with 3V Vgs you can make the channel fully open by (1) using a level shifter to shift Vgs 3V to 10V, say. (2) Shift ground/base level which is actually another level shifter. But shifting level cost time and money. So if you can bear a bigger Rds(on) without heat sink, that might be a good trade off. Cheers.

Comment: At 7A with 3V Gate drive Rdson is such that it drops ~1.2V, which equates to a power loss of 1.2*7 = 8.4W. And this is just the 'typical' value. If the actual Gate threshold is higher it will be worse. If you want to switch up to 10A then you should choose a FET with lower Rdson. I usually aim for a worst-case voltage drop of 0.1V, which equates to Rdson = 0.01 Ohms at 10A.

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks for the tip with the level shifter. I might use one.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott  I understand what you are saying, but how did you get these numbers? Where in the datasheet can i see what the Rds for a given Vgs/ID is? How do you know it drops 1.2V at 7A and 3V Vgs? Am i missing something in the datasheet, or did you calculate it.Sorry if im missing something obvious, im still new to electronics.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott Is it not easy to explain, or did miss my question? Does anybody else know the answer how to get Rdson for a given Vgs? Would love to know it, seems really usefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rds(on) specification says that if you pass a drain current of 8A, with the specified Vgs, the Rds(on) (And therefore Vds) will be as listed. The 8A is limited by external means.

If you try to pass a very high current the MOSFET will behave differently and Vds will increase faster than you’d expect from a fixed resistance. Once Vds starts to look significant compared to Vgs..

Comment: oh, i understand. really just test conditions then. so the only id that tells plainly me what the maximum A is that the mosfet can handle is the id line in the specs table, correct?
And what is a significant difference in your eyes?

Comment: The maximum current the MOSFET can "handle" is usually limited by package, by SOA (safe operating area) and by thermal limits (so your maximum ambient temperature, the heatsink (if any) and the way the heat sink is attached, any cooling air or conduction etc. etc.).  Id (continuous) at Tc = 100°C may be a useful rough number.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Could you clarify what you mean by "Once Vds starts to look significant compared to Vgs". What difference is siginificant?

Comment: The MOSFET is said to be in the saturation region when Vds > Vgs - Vth. It's not exactly a sharp transition as you can see from [this](https://i.imgur.com/ro2Sn51.png) curve from your datasheet, the linear or ohmic region (constant Rds(on)) is where the curve has a constant slope starting from 0,0. For high Vds relative to Vgs - Vth the curve becomes almost flat (like a constant current).  For a switch usually you are going to want Vds << Vgs - Vth.